# How to change the color of an object created with JSONLoader on click

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've started working with Three.js recently and created an object using the JSONLoader. The whole object contains a material with a grey color.

Now i just want to be able to change a color of the object by clicking on a button I've added to my HTML.

```
<input type="button" value="Change Color" onClick="group.material.color.setHex('0xffffff')">
```

DevTools delivers following message:

***Cannot read property 'color' of undefined***

Well, I checked if the object contains the property color and of course it doesn't.

I knew it wouldn't work, but the hope dies last. Here is the part where the object is getting created:

```
group = new THREE.Object3D();

    //load mesh 
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('models/s_class.js',  function( geometry ) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x2f3a4c}) );
        mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
        mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
        mesh.position.y = 0;
        group.add( mesh );
        scene.add( group );
    } );
```

Please, is there ANY way to simply change a color by pressing a button? Do I have to build my object with another Loader maybe?

[Here is my code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/accneeder/w9q83yy5/)

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the color of the "group", but the children. E.g. use the traverse function.

```
 group.traverse(function(child) {
    if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
          child.material.color.setHex('0xffffff');
    }
 });
```

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you very very much :)